# RSA Archer Data Feed JS Transporter setup

Tags: javascript, api, feed, archer

Does anyone have a working example of a data feed using a JS Transporter for API data extraction? The summit example "google api" one does not work for me and the youtube channel does not provide the index.js to assist.

Comment: If you run the JS in Visual Studio Code (make sure NodeJS is installed) what errors do you get?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far. There is a sample file but it isn't much help. I was wondering if there was a working example .js file out there I could look at. For this job I have to get a bearer token and then grab the data.

Comment: There's a bunch of JS integration feeds on the www.archerirm.community Product > Downloads > Exchange Downloads.  Search for Qualys which I think has what you're looking for.  Or search for Integration for that category for others.

Comment: Wow thanks! this is a great resource.